# Keyboard works--but suddenly won't type anything. What's up?

Tags: keyboard

Note that all the hardware works, a reboot fixes it.  It's just the third time this has happened and it's getting annoying.

Suddenly, with no apparent trigger I can no longer actually type anything.  I can't get anything on the system to admit there are keypresses but they **are** actually getting through.  The system reacts normally to any keypress that doesn't generate a typed character.  I can run a virtual keyboard, it will correctly show things like the shift state, but it doesn't show ordinary keys.  The keys work, though--it appears everything you can do with a keyboard other than enter characters is fine.  Function keys work, cut & paste works etc.  The virtual keyboard has no problem entering characters.  After a cut & paste it sometimes starts spewing v's like it's stuck, but slower than the repeat rate I have configured.  Poking the v to try to unstick it does nothing, but poking keys that actually get through will stop the repeating.

I'm running VMWare, all virtual machines have the same failure.  I have a couple of other input editors installed, switching languages doesn't clear the problem.  Unplugging the keyboard doesn't fix it.

Comment: Did you try a USB Keyboard (or a different Keyboard if already USB)?

Comment: @John I didn't think of trying another keyboard.  Next time it happens I'll have to try that.  There are other keyboards in the house but I'm not sure if there are any USB ones.

Comment: The point is more a different keyboard so long as it connects to the computer.

Comment: @John Happened again, plugged in a USB keyboard, exactly the same behavior.  Anything that doesn't generate a character works, anything that does fails.